# Count how many times a word occurs in an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an array not an array list. And I need to count how many times a certain word occurs in it. I keep searching online and all I see is how to find a word in an array list. Do I have to convert my array to an array list? Very new to java. Thanks.

Comment: No you don't have to.

Comment: Iterate, evaluate, sum. You can iterate over an `Array` so you can do it.

Comment: `int numOccurrences = Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(array), word);`

Comment: `int count = (int) Stream.of(array).filter(x -> word.equals(x)).count();`

Answer (score 1):

#### Firstly

Could you provide an example of your code please? This allows people can have a better idea of what you mean, making it easier to help you.

#### Secondly

No, you don't need to convert to an ArrayList. Moreover, according to what you said, I am assuming you have string objects inside the array. If this is the case you can use something like the example below:

```
String [] words = new String [lengthOfYourArray];
String wordToSearchFor = "hello"; /* change this to what you want to search for*/

// Assuming the array already has elements before iterating with for each loop

int count = 0;
for(String word : words){
    if(word.equals(wordToSearchFor)) 
        count++;
}

/* Assuming you're using the console screen for data output */
System.out.println(count); /* Display the counter for that particular word */
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to direct message it to you? I can't really show some of my code it won't make any sense. It's a bit all over the place.

Comment: Just as a side note: if you want to count words within the array reguardless of upper or lower letter case then you may want to use: `if(word.equalsIgnoreCase(wordToSearchFor)) count++;`

Comment: @user7520940 post it onto sololearn questions page, then  message me the title. I will look at it there or you can message it to me at Ousmane_Mahy_Diaw on twitter.